# ERROR: compilation failed for package 'digest'

Tags: r

When installing summarytools I get a dependency for digest package in R. But I get a complication error when installing digest on RStudio. I'm installing on Windows. Following is the complete error message.

```
*** arch - i386
make: *** No rule to make target '$(CXX11STD)''.  Stop.
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'digest'
* removing 'C:/Users/R00182486/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/digest'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘digest’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: What version of R do you have?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I encountered this problem installing "digest" (using R studio, R 3.6.3). I tried many solutions proposed in another thread on this topic (installing from zipped folder, from tar.gz file, etc.) with no success.

However, when I used Tools>>Install Packages>>Install from Repository (CRAN), entered the package name, and chose "No" when the pop-up prompted "Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation?" the installation completed without throwing errors.

I've run several packages with the same dependency on digest and all seem to be working fine now. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

After some similar issues after updating R to 4.3.1 I updated Rtools to RTools43, which solved my problem with digest not compiling.